# Tab '\t' in alert box not working with Chrome

Tags: javascript

I want to display three lines of text in a Javascript alert box with center alignment of text.

I'm using the following code for that,

```
alert(
    '\t\t\t\t'+"Congratulations!" + '\n\t' +
    "You are now subscribed with test.com!" + '\n' +
    "Keep on eye out on your inbox for future updates from us!"
);
```

It's working fine with Firefox. But in chrome, the tab (`\t`) character is not working. Texts are left aligned in all lines. Please help.

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on text positioning in `alert()` boxes. You also really shouldn't use an alert box for telling someone they're subscribed. Just put a message on the page.

Comment: alertbox is waaaaaay aged man ! try other cool things like colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox  and also alertbox is a part of the browser ,which has minimal style functionalities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to have been an issue for awhile sadly :(

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/bfmvqAvtSd4

Found that and it makes it out to look like it's not possible.

Perhaps use something that'd mimic an alert box in appearance?

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you can use several spaces instead.  E.g...

```
<script>
    alert('Food:\n   Apples\n   Bread\n   Carrots');
</script>
```

A working example:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#btnShowAlert').on('click', function(){
    alert('Food:\n   Apples\n   Bread\n   Carrots');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnShowAlert">Show Alert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
alert("Name: " + "\u00A0" + "Jose " + "\u00A0" + "Garcia");
```

`\u00A0` is the non-breaking space character. I know it's now a tab per say, but `\t` gives me a weird line before the text like this:
`-Text`, so I ended up using `\u00A0` instead. Hope this helps!